polars python collecting a list
I am trying to group_by and look for groups that have different ids for the same data using polars. The error I am getting is: Error: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'collect_list'. Here is my code:
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

# Create a sample DataFrame with detailed personal data where all fields are the same except the client ID
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "PER_FirstName": ["John", "John", "John"],
    "PER_LastName": ["Doe", "Doe", "Doe"],
    "PER_DOB": [datetime(1990, 5, 1), datetime(1990, 5, 1), datetime(1990, 5, 1)],
    "PER_StreetAddress": ["123 Elm St", "123 Elm St", "123 Elm St"],
    "PER_ClientID": [101, 102, 103]
})


# Using group_by and trying a potentially available function.
try:
    result = df.group_by(['PER_FirstName', 'PER_LastName', 'PER_DOB', 'PER_StreetAddress']) \
               .agg([
                   pl.col('PER_ClientID').n_unique().alias('unique_client_ids'),
                   pl.col('PER_ClientID').collect_list().alias('client_ids')  # Trying collect_list
               ])
    print(result)
except AttributeError as e:
    print("Error:", e)

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how to change it so it works? Thank you!

I ended up using a combination of polars and pandas to solve it. Apparently there is currently no polars facility to collect stuff the way I wanted so I went with a hybrid approach like so:
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from itables import show

# Aggregate to collect unique client IDs and count them
result = df.groupby(['PER_FirstName', 'PER_LastName', 'PER_DOB', 'PER_StreetAddress']) \
           .agg([
               pl.col('PER_ClientID').unique().alias('unique_client_ids'),
               pl.col('PER_ClientID').n_unique().alias('count_unique_ids')
           ])

# Filter groups with exactly two unique client IDs
filtered_result = result.filter(pl.col('count_unique_ids') > 1)

# Convert Polars DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
filtered_result_pd = filtered_result.to_pandas()

# Display the result using itables
#show(filtered_result_pd)

from itables import init_notebook_mode
from itables import show

init_notebook_mode(all_interactive=True)

show(filtered_result_pd, classes="display nowrap compact",paging=False, buttons=["copyHtml5", "csvHtml5", "excelHtml5"], scrollX = True)

